# Queue-ing multiple subprocesses

Tags: python-3.x, bash, subprocess

I need some help with controlling subprocesses.
I am really not sure which direction of code I need to do/research on as well.

As of the moment, I am controlling the running of a software using python as seen in the code below.

```py
import subprocess

# Declaring some input and output names for the third-party program
label = ['fname1', 'fname2', 'fname3', 'fname4']
input_list = [ 'inp.'+ l for l in label ]
output_list = [ 'out.'+ l for l in label ]

# Run all sets of input and output using the third-party software
for in, out in zip(input_list, output_list):
    #The bash command to run the executable
    command = f"mpirun pw.x < {in} > {out}" 
    subprocess.run(command, shell=True)
```

My computer has 64 logical cores and as I've tested with the software, using 32 and 64 doesn't change the speed of the calculation, hence, I would like to edit the code to accomodate two concurrent subprocess.run's with `mpirun -n 32 ...`.

I don't know how to do the concurrent stuff, like queue-ing and controlling how many instance of the subprocess is allowed to run at a given time.

May I ask which module/library will help me get this done ? of course a code sample will be very much appreciated.

> P.S. PBS/SLURM systems are not an option because I am also doing some processing stuff within the python script.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the `concurrent.futures` module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if you want to run `mpirun -n 32` twice in parallel:

```
import concurrent.futures

labels = ['fname1', 'fname2']
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=len(labels)) as pool:
    for label in labels:
        command = f"mpirun -n 32 pw.x < inp.{label} > out.{label}"
        pool.submit(subprocess.run, command, shell=True)
```

The `with` statement will close the pool at the end, which makes it wait for all the jobs to complete.

Comment: Thank you for this! I just have a question, what happens if there are 3 commands that need to run? will the 3rd "instance" run after one of the initial two finishes ? or does it wait for both to finish ?

Comment: With max_workers limited to 2, the third job would wait for any available worker, meaning the third job would start when the quickest of the first two jobs completes.  Waiting for all jobs only happens at the end of the `with` block.